# Input field html5 placeholder doesn't go away after value added in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder

On that web page I have input fields that use the [Mike Taylor html5 placeholder](https://github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder).  I assign values to the input fields in javascript like this.

```
document.add_event_form.end_time.value = time_array[0];
```

The placeholder after that is still visible under the value given to that field.  Is there a way to make the placeholder aware that a value was specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually hide the `<label>` element which that placeholder plugin generates.

```
document.add_event_form.end_time.value = time_array[0];
var id = $(document.add_event_form.end_time).attr("id");
$("label[for='"+ id +"']").hide();
```

Alternatively, you could trigger the `focus()` and `blur()` events for that input because those are the same events that the placeholder plugin uses.

```
document.add_event_form.end_time.value = time_array[0];
$(document.add_event_form.end_time).focus().blur();
```

*NOTE: Since the plugin you're using replies on jQuery, so does my answer.*

Comment: The first alternative `$("label[for='"+ id +"']").hide();` 
fixed the problem.  Thanks.